# Is it worthwhile to buy an 802.11ac Wi-Fi card when I'm running on 2.4GHz Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I currently have a 802.11ac router on my home network. However, my house's walls mean that the 5Ghz signal does not make it upstairs. As a result, I have connected all my upstairs devices onto the 2.4Ghz network instead.

My question is, would it be any faster to have an 802.11ac card for a computer upstairs compared to an 802.11n card, given that it will be using only 2.4GHz?

Comment: Paired with a 5GHz-compatible repeater, it would be interesting, if only to prevent congestion on the 2.4GHz channel(s) you use downstairs on your other devices. Otherwise, I don't see the point, but others here may think differently.

Comment: You do understand that `802.11ac` is 5.0 GHz only?  So a wireless adapter that is 802.11ac would require two antennas.  One that was configured to support WiFi 5 and another one for a version of the standard that supported 2.4 GHz.